# How can I calculate Fibonacci of Fibonacci iteratively K times in sublinear time?

Tags: sequences-and-series, computational-complexity, fibonacci-numbers, matrix-exponential

For example for $K=3$ time and $N=6$,

$Fib(Fib(Fib(6)))
=Fib(Fib(8))
=Fib(21)
=10946
$

Note I need the answer modulo a large integer(say P).
ie formally speaking calculate in most efficient way:

$Fib(Fib(Fib(.....K times.....Fib(N)))\ modulo\ P$ where P is a given integer.

My thoughts:

I am aware of [how to calculate](https://levelup.gitconnected.com/how-to-calculate-the-fibonacci-sequence-in-logarithmic-time-abde842f5a39) $i_{th}$ Fibonacci number $\ modulo\ P$ in $O(log(P))$.
So taking that approach I can at best calculate it iteratively looping K times ie overall complexity will be $O(K\ log(P))$ but I believe it would be possible to do it in sublinear time, maybe something like $O(log(K)\ P^{0.25})$
or $O(log^2(K)\ P^{0.25})$ or $O(K^{0.25}\ P^{0.25})$

Here are the series for [K = 2](http://oeis.org/A007570) and [K = 3](http://oeis.org/A058051)

Comment: Complexity presumably depends on $P$, not just $K$. If you can do it in $O(\log K)$ for any $P$, that implies you can find $\operatorname{Fib}(N) \operatorname{modulo} P$ in $O(1)$ for any $P$.

Comment: Is this a CodeChef or Project Euler problem, or something like that? The requirement to get the answer modulo a $64$-bit integer comes up often in these competitions.

Comment: @GerryMyerson it is not part of any active competetion that I am aware of but I guess it  was framed keeping them in mind. Mind you unlike most  competition problems here $P$ might be a contributor to the time complexity itself, it's not just a fashionable variable to keep calculations small

Answer (score 3):

As you are considering Fibonacci numbers modulo some number P, you could take advantage of [Pisano periods](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pisano_period).

Concretely, for $K = 3$, if $\pi(n)$ denotes the period of Fibonacci numbers modulo $n$ and $\pi^k$ the [k-th iterate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iterated_function#Definition) of $\pi$ (for example, $\pi^2(P) = \pi(\pi(P))$), you have this identity:

$Fib(Fib(Fib(v)))\ modulo\ P = Fib(Fib(Fib(v\ modulo\ \pi^3(P))\ modulo\ \pi^2(P))\ modulo\ \pi(P))\ modulo\ P$

This result can be obtained as follows:

- Fibonacci numbers modulo $P$ are $\pi(P)$ periodic,
- so $Fib(Fib(Fib(v)))\ modulo\ P = Fib(Fib(Fib(v))\ modulo\ \pi(P))\ modulo\ P$,
- Fibonacci numbers modulo $\pi(P)$ are $\pi^2(P)$ periodic,
- so $Fib(Fib(Fib(v)))\ modulo\ P = Fib(Fib(Fib(v)\ modulo\ \pi^2(P))\ modulo\ \pi(P))\ modulo\ P$,
- Fibonacci numbers modulo $\pi^2(P)$ are $\pi^3(P)$ periodic,
- so $Fib(Fib(Fib(v)))\ modulo\ P = Fib(Fib(Fib(v\ modulo\ \pi^3(P))\ modulo\ \pi^2(P))\ modulo\ \pi(P))\ modulo\ P.$

Of course, determining Pisano periods adds complexity, and some of the required $\pi^k(P)$ may not fit in 64 bits.

Comment: What is your intended time complexity? If we calculate pisano period using prime factorization method then it's complexity would be $O(P^{0.25})$. so if we have to get for each of the K iterates then it's $O(K\ P^{0.25})$ which I believe is not better than $O(K\ log(P))$ that I already have.

Comment: I am sure pisano will play a vital role in getting time complexity down but your answer may not be the complete story.

Comment: I guess there can be period in the series  $π(P), π^2(P), π^3(P) .... π^K(P)$ which can be used to optimise on top of your approach.  We have to figure out the upper bound of that period value.

Comment: $\pi$ has fixed points (see [OEIS A235702](https://oeis.org/A235702)), and a quick test on small values of $P$ suggests that we always reach such a fixed point when iterating $\pi$. See also [OEIS A235249](https://oeis.org/A235249).

Comment: I see then the question becomes how long does it take to reach such a fixed point.. if that max iteration to reach fixed point is S. then complexity becomes $O(S\ P^{0.25} + S\ log(P))$

Comment: Another Interesting observation is number of  fixed points is quite small(ie till 10k fixed points are 10, 24,120,600,3000,75000,15000), so there might be lots of common path to fixed point for multiple values of P. It would be interesting if path tree for each fixed point can be pre-computed. It would enable us to bring down the average time in case we need to calculate for multiple cases of different P.

Comment: http://oeis.org/A235702 .. “Fixed Points” of the Pisano Function are of $24 . 5^n$ form https://jain108academy.com/216-code-pisano-function/